# Unfold a plain-object with array of plain-objects into a flat plain-object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, combinatorics

*update*: I described the problem in a wrong way and have rewritten the description completely, along with the code that works but is ugly as hell as well as limited.

---

Let's pretend there's an object

```
const input = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
  c: {
    d: true,
    e: '4'
  },
  f: [{
    g: 5,
    h: {
      i: '6'
    }
  }, {
    g: 7,
    h: {
      i: '8'
    }
  }]
}
```

what I'm looking for is a collection of all possible arrangements of nested arrays, with object's keys flattened and joined with ".", like

```
[{
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
  'c.d': true,
  'c.e': '4',
  'f.g': 5,
  'f.h.i': '6'
}, {
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
  'c.d': true,
  'c.e': '4',
  'f.g': 7,
  'f.h.i': '8'
}]
```

Note that there are no keys that would have non-primitive values, for example, `'f.h'` that would point at an object.

So, what I do first, is collect all the keys, and artificially add `#` sign to every key that points at an array item, so `#` kind of means "every index in that array":

```
function columns(data, prefix = '') {
  if (_.isArray(data)) {
    return columns(_.first(data), `${prefix}.#`);
  } else if (_.isObject(data)) {
    return _.filter(_.flatMap(_.keys(data), key => {
      return _.concat(
        !_.isObject(_.result(data, key)) ? `${prefix}.${key}` : null,
        columns(data[key], `${prefix}.${key}`)
      );
    }));
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(columns(input)); // -> [".a", ".b", ".c.d", ".c.e", ".f.#.g", ".f.#.h.i"]
```

Now, I wield lodash. The leading "." in keys isn't a problem for lodash, so I just leave it as is. With lodash, I squash the object into a one-level object with weird keys:

```
function flattenKeys(original, keys) {
  return _.mapValues(_.groupBy(_.map(keys, key => ({
    key,
    value: _.result(original, key)
  })), 'key'), e => _.result(e, '0.value'));
}

console.log(flattenKeys(input, columns(input))) // -> {".a":1,".b":"2",".c.d":true,".c.e":"4"}
```

And now I run (in a very wrong way) through every array-like property of original object and produce an array of objects, setting keys like `.f.#.h.i` with the values of `.f.0.h.i` for first element, etc.:

```
function unfold(original, keys, iterables) {
  if (!_.isArray(iterables)) {
    return unfold(original, keys, _.uniq(_.map(_.filter(keys, key => /#/i.test(key)), key => _.replace(key, /\.\#.*/, ''))));
  } else if (_.isEmpty(iterables)) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const first = _.first(iterables);
    const rest = _.tail(iterables);
    const values = _.result(original, first);
    const flatKeys = _.mapKeys(_.filter(keys, key => _.includes(key, first)));
    const updated = _.map(values, (v, i) => ({
      ...flattenKeys(original, keys),
      ..._.mapValues(flatKeys, k => _.result(original, _.replace(k, /\#/, i)))
    }));

    return _.concat(updated, unfold(original, keys, rest));
  }
}

console.log(unfold(input, columns(input))) // -> [{".a":1,".b":"2",".c.d":true,".c.e":"4",".f.#.g":5,".f.#.h.i":"6"},{".a":1,".b":"2",".c.d":true,".c.e":"4",".f.#.g":7,".f.#.h.i":"8"}]
```

So in the end, I only need to clean keys, which, in fact, isn't necessary in my case.

The question is, aside of ugliness of the code, how can I make it work with possible multiple array-like properties in original objects?

---

Now, I understand, that this question is more suitable for CodeReview StackExchange, so if somebody transfers it there, I'm okay with that.

Comment: Is it only two levels or arbitrarily many?

Comment: Is there always exactly one element in those arrays? What would it mean if not? And if yes, why do you use these arrays in the first place?

Comment: Just discovered that an array may contain multiple elements, but is never empty. I have working code but man, how nasty it is. I'll share it, though.

Comment: Your updated example does something entirely different than the previous, now every object is containing all of the flattened keys. And it's not clear at all how you arrive at the values `'f.g': 7` and `'f.h.i': '8'`. Please fix the example; best include multiple ones.

Comment: Sure, updated. I'm this close to just deleting this question  but holding it for history and in belief that somebody may bump into the same combinatoric problem with exactly the same setting.

Comment: Ah, *now* it begins to make sense. So you just want to "multiply" arrays with each other, not keys between objects. I'll post a recursive solution soon :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated structure, the following recursive function does the trick:

```
function unfold(input) {
  function flatten(obj) {
    var result = {},
        f,
        key,
        keyf;

    for(key in obj) {
      if(obj[key] instanceof Array) {
        obj[key].forEach(function(k) {
          f = flatten(k);
          for(keyf in f) {
            result[key+'.'+keyf] = f[keyf];
          }
          output.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))); //poor man's clone object
        });
      } else if(obj[key] instanceof Object) {
        f = flatten(obj[key]);
        for(keyf in f) {
          result[key+'.'+keyf] = f[keyf];
        }
      } else {
        result[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }
    return result;
  } //flatten

  var output = [];
  flatten(input);
  return output;
} //unfold
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function unfold(input) {
  function flatten(obj) {
    var result = {},
        f,
        key,
        keyf;

    for(key in obj) {
      if(obj[key] instanceof Array) {
        obj[key].forEach(function(k) {
          f = flatten(k);
          for(keyf in f) {
            result[key+'.'+keyf] = f[keyf];
          }
          output.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))); //poor man's clone object
        });
      } else if(obj[key] instanceof Object) {
        f = flatten(obj[key]);
        for(keyf in f) {
          result[key+'.'+keyf] = f[keyf];
        }
      } else {
        result[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }
    return result;
  } //flatten
  
  var output = [];
  flatten(input);
  return output;
} //unfold

const input = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
  c: {
    d: true,
    e: '4'
  },
  f: [{
    g: 5,
    h: {
      i: '6'
    }
  }, {
    g: 7,
    h: {
      i: '8'
    }
  }]
};

document.body.innerHTML+= '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(unfold(input), null, 2) + '</pre>';
```

---

I'll leave my original answer, which worked with your original structure:

```js
var o = {a: [{b: 1, c: 2}], d: [{e: 4, f: 5}]},
    keys = Object.keys(o),
    result = [];

keys.forEach(function(i, idx1) {
  keys.forEach(function(j, idx2) {
    if(idx2 > idx1) { //avoid duplicates
      for(var k in o[i][0]) {
       for(var l in o[j][0]) {
          result.push({
            [i + '.' + k]: o[i][0][k],
            [j + '.' + l]: o[j][0][l]
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I can see at least two tricks in this code I would not have come up with myself. That's insanely cool, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure thing, it was a fun challenge.

Comment: This appears to break down if the outer object has not exactly two properties. And if it does, you should just hardcode that…

Comment: @Bergi, you're absolutely right, and now that the question has been updated with a more complicated structure, my code doesn't work at all.  However, I'll leave it since the OP said he found a couple tricks in it he could use.